# Contactless Card like visa Paywave using Magnetic Stripe Data

Tags: contactless-smartcard, mastercard

I have a **[nRF5240](https://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/nRF52840)** BLE chip which supports NFC Type 2 and Type 4 tag emulation protocol stack.

Is it possible to emulate a Contactless Card like Visa payWave or Mastercard PayPass which has Magnetic Stripe Data on it ?? If yes how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scenario is similar to [HCE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_card_emulation) application which runs on phones.  There are certain protocols that dictate how to respond to terminal commands(in hardware terms). If your chip is able to communicate with terminal then you need software to communicate with terminal. When your card is in distance of contactless terminal certain [apdu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_card_application_protocol_data_unit) commands sent to card to start a transaction. if you could code correctly you can get almost similar behaviour as PayWave or PayPass application.

During transaction, terminal could send your transaction to verify online then you have to know Issuer(Bank) keys. There is a small chance(offline limits are not exceeded) that you could get offline transaction but you have to know Issuer Certificates(it is based on RSA and dynamic values). This is harder to crack then online transactions, online keys.

Yes you could get your complete PayWave or PayPass card but you could not breach security.